# Error 404 on Symfony2

Tags: apache, symfony, routes

I have 3 symfony2 apps, 2 work fine, but the third just works for the default page. The rest of the routes throw a 404 error. Environment is: Ubunto 12.04 VirtualBox, apache 2, php 5.3.10, Mongobd.

This is de VHost content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/adminuser/webs/servergrove/web
    ServerName servergrove.local
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/servergrove-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/servergrove-access.log combined
    <Directory /home/adminuser/webs/servergrove/web>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the routing.yml:

```
homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: SGLiveChatBundle:Default:index }

sglc_chat_homepage:
    pattern:  /sglivechat
    defaults: { _controller: SGLiveChatBundle:Chat:index }

sglc_chat_invite:
    pattern: /sglivechat/{sessId}/invite
    defaults: { _controller: SGLiveChatBundle:Chat:invite }
```

... and so on.

The following url works fine: http://servergrove.local/

The following (and any other) doesn't: http://servergrove.local/sglivechat

```
*Not Found
The requested URL /sglivechat was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at servergrove.local Port 80*
```

I have very little experience with symfony. I'd think is related with rewrite engine, but the other two projects works ok.

I've got something like this on the command line:

adminuser@adminuser-VirtualBox-073n:~/webs/servergrove$ php app/console router:debug

```
[router] Current routes
    Name   Method Pattern
    homepage         ANY    /
    sglc_admin_index GET    /admin/sglivechat
    prueba           ANY    /prueba
```

adminuser@adminuser-VirtualBox-073n:~/webs/servergrove$ php app/console router:dump-apache

```
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^/$
RewriteRule .* app.php [QSA,L,E=_ROUTING__route:homepage,E=_ROUTING__controller:ServerGrove\SGLiveChatBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(get) [NC]
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^/admin/sglivechat$
RewriteRule .* app.php [QSA,L,E=_ROUTING__route:sglc_admin_index,E=_ROUTING__controller:ServerGrove\SGLiveChatBundle\Controller\AdminController::indexAction]

RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^/prueba$
RewriteRule .* app.php [QSA,L,E=_ROUTING__route:prueba,E=_ROUTING__controller:ServerGrove\SGLiveChatBundle\Controller\DefaultController::pruebaAction]
```

Any idea of what can be wrong?

Comment: At the beginning of appKernel.php I added: a die('aaaa');, if I browse http://servergrove.local/ I see aaaa, but in any other url I see the same 404 error.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` looks `awfully` complex :-| Have you tried restoring it to default one?

Comment: Your application is not reconising your routes as you can see when you run `php app/console router:debug` command. It could be for various reasons but with the information you give us is difficult to know. The only thing that I can tell you is that is not apache problem as the routes are not dumped. Could you post please the `routing.yml` file located in your `/app/config` folder?

Comment: the routing file contents:
`code`
    sglivechat:
        resource: @SGLiveChatBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
the other routing contents begins with:
`code`
homepage:
  pattern:  /
  defaults: { _controller: SGLiveChatBundle:Default:index }
#  defaults: { _controller: SGLiveSGLiveChatBundle:Default:index } 

# -- Live Chat -----------------------------------------------------------------

prueba:
  pattern:  /prueba
  defaults: { _controller: SGLiveChatBundle:Default:prueba }


sglc_chat_homepage:
    pattern:  /sglivechat
    defaults: { _controller: SGLiveChatBundle:Chat:index }

Comment: by the way, if I use http://servergrove.local/app_dev.php/sglivechat instead of http://servergrove.local/sglivechat, I can see the app ok. It looks like the apache is not rewriting the url, but I don-t know how to fix this.
Thanxs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that the route works fine with the app_dev.php; so the problem could be fixed doing the next:

- Verify if you have the .htaccess file in the web directory.
- Ensure your apache server have the mod_rewrite module enabled.
- Erase the cache in your prod environment.

Comment: Thanks, Finally, after a couple of hours reviewing about the htaccess file, I got the short urls.